# Development mode on Symfony2 virtual hosts

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, virtualhost

I was boring about my large url `http://localhost:8888/site/web/app_dev.php`, so, I created `apache virtual hosts`. When I write `http://site.dev` in my browser, everything is working, my website appears.

The problem is that my Symfony2 website seems to be in dev / prod mode whereas I point to `app_dev.php` (in the `.htaccess`).

I have the debug bottom toolbar (it shows me "dev environment"), I can do dumps, but when I modify a file (JS, Twig, and so on), I have to execute, each time, `php app/console assetic:dump` (I hadn't before).

My virtual host :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site.dev
    ServerAlias www.site.dev

    DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bo/web
    <Directory /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bo/web>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

EDIT : I noticed that the website is so much faster like that (site.dev) than before (with the localhost URL). Don't know why, and still don't know how to fix the `php app/console assetic:dump` problem...

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have any other problems but worrying about the lengths of the URL? :)

But seriously, try starting the internal PHP/Symfony server with the following command:

```
$ app/console server:start
```

The development version of your app will be at http://localhost:8000. Nice and short.

---

Based on your comment, it turns out that the actual problem you have is hardcoding URLs in your JS. The solution for that is https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle.

Basically, that bundle lets you expose routes to your JS so that you avoid hardcoding URLs there.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not helping me at all. I know how to use Symfony2 server, just want to have a shorter url for a JS trick that I use on my website :)

Comment: It's a hard-coding path in a JS file, the path is different between my production server and my local, that's why I want to use the same url pattern

Comment: Thanks. I already use it, but more for urls that type : http://site.dev/login but not for relative ones like /web/bundles/mybundle/, so, how can I do to have the relative path to mybundle ?

Answer (score 0):

You need add this line *DirectoryIndex  app.php*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName site.dev
     ServerAlias www.site.dev

     DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bo/web
     DirectoryIndex  app.php
     <Directory /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bo/web>
         AllowOverride All
         Order Allow,Deny
         Allow from All
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It's working but still have to execute "php app/console assetic:dump"